# Getting content from editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application, i have a tableLayout with many editTexts in it. When i click "save"button, i want to access all the values entered in editTexts. I have assigned IDs in runtime while creating the table. Now how can i access the values from editTexts when "save" button is clicked...? I have used something like below to assign IDs,

```
for(int i=0;i< no_of_rows ;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  {   
    ...............
    assignment.setId(i+j);
    .............
  }
```

Could anyone suggest a solution..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other nice solution is to cycle through all childrens of some Layout, so you don't need to set any special IDs. Just try:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
child_count = layout.getChildCount();

for (int i=0; i<child_count; i++)
{
    EditText text = (EditText) layout.getChildAt(i);
    // do work with text
}
```

With some other code, you can do this for any other layout hierarchy.

Comment: I have 3 rows in the table layout and i m getting childCount as 3. In each row, i have 2 textEdits, can i access them using getChildAt()..?

Comment: i got it. Will post the updated answer in a while. :) Thanks teepee :)

Comment: make sure you catch `ClassCastExceptions` with this code, if not all your views are `EditTexts`.

Comment: oops! Bcz of less reputation, i could not post the answer. I used the below code to access all the editTexts. TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.assignTable);for(int i=1,k=0;i<=row_count;i++,k+=10){TableRow row=(TableRow)layout.getChildAt(i);
for(int j=2;j<4;j++){EditText e1 = (EditText)row.findViewById(j+k);
readValues[i-1][j]=e1.getText().toString();}
         
} here,assignTable is the table in which i created all the rows. For 5 editTexts in each row, IDs are 0 1 2 3 4 ..in first row,10,11,12,13,14 in 2nd row..so on.readValues stores all the values as a 2-d string array.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i< no_of_rows ;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  {   
    EditText text = (EditText)ActivityName.this.findViewById(i+j);
    strings.add(text.getText().toString());
  }
}
```

This would give you all of the values from all of the texts in one big array.  If that's not what you want, let me know and I'll see if I can adjust the code.

Comment: Line, EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(i+j) , is throwing classCastException..

Comment: I've updated my answer, although it is a little hard to know what's wrong without seeing more of your code

Comment: Its still giving the same problem. which part of the code do you wish to view...?

Comment: The context - what class are you calling this in, and what method?  Could you update your question to include this, but skip out any irrelevant bits of code.  Also, if you could post logcat output that would help with debugging

Comment: 08-08 01:51:18.776: WARN/dalvikvm(430): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-08 01:51:18.776: WARN/dalvikvm(430): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-08 01:51:18.796: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
................................ this is a part of logcat output.

Comment: Are you trying to cast a TextView to an EditText?

Comment: I have included your code in onClick() function..., and i havent tried any casting there.

Comment: @VickiD let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2201/discussion-between-kishan-and-vicki-d)